# Unable to deploy Mule app on mule standalone server

Tags: mule

While using the Mule Maven plug-in to deploy the deployable archive on the Mule standalone server I receive this error intermittently.

```
Error : Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
Could not rename C:\mule-standalone\mule-ee-distribution-standalone-3.4.0\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.0\apps\**MyProject.zip**.temp
to C:\mule-standalone\mule-ee-distribution-standalone-3.4.0\mule-enterprise-standalone-3.4.0\apps\**MyProject.zip**
```

I am using the following Maven plug-in:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
   <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you have a file opened in the mule apps folder. The maven-mule plugin is not able to rename /delete the older app and as a result the build fails.